# Python - Iterating over a list of dataframes to create new variables

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, data-manipulation

I am new to Python and would like to ask for help using for loops

I have a dataframe of stock codes and prices which I have split using the groupby function into the respective stock codes as per below

`grouped = list(dft.groupby(dft.StockCode))`

What I'm trying to do is a for loop that iterates over the list of dataframes to create a new variable in each dataframe. For example, I would like to calculate the RSI for each stock code.

```
for df in grouped:
    df['RSI']=ta.RSI(df['Close'],14)
```

I could do this individually by splitting out each stock code and then calculating it but it would be a very time consuming process and I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
dft_new = dft.groupby('StockCode').apply(lambda x: ta.RSI(x, 14))
```

I haven't tested it. But the idea is to use [pandas apply on groups](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html).